# Android Emulator never fully starts

Tags: android, emulation, virtual, android-virtual-device

When I run built-in AVDs using the Android Virtual Device Manager  (API levels 10 and 12) Android boots up fine. Unfortunately when I try to run an AVD with a newer versions of the API it fails (I've tried both 4 and 4.4.2). Here are steps I took.

1. Ran Android SDK manager and downloaded all the available Android packages
2. Using the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager I created a device definition copying all settings for default Nexus 5 phone.
3. I then created an AVD with following settings

   - Device: nexus5clonedevice
   - Target: Android 4.4.1 API Level 19
   - CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi-v7a)
   - Keyboard: unchecked
   - Skin: No Skin
   - Back Camera: None
   - Front Camera: None
   - RAM: 768 (also tried  2048)
   - VM HEAP: 64
   - Internal Storage: 16 GB
   - SD Card: 16 GB
   - Emulation options: (both unchecked)
   - (Launched the AVD with nothing checked)

The AVD starts but instead of getting android I get a black box that doesn't do anything. I read in another thread that waiting might help but I tried waiting for over 30 minutes to no avail. (running this on windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit with 12 GB RAM)

Comment: Why us Emulator when you can save time with GenyMotion. It's a great alternative, boots up quickly and works quicker than device.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, does the emulated device show up in the Devices view? If so, does anything show up in logcat? What happens if you simply use the Nexus 5 phone as the device?

Comment: any thing interesting in logcat? some errors maybe?

Comment: To address comments. I'm using Xamarin through Visual Studio. When I try setting up a AVD using stock Nexus 5 device it has the same problem. Blank window appears but Android never fully starts. I don't know where to look for logcat.

Answer (score 3):

The Android Emulator is very slow. I recommend you use [Genymotion Emulator](https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc) which is very fast compared to the Android Emulator or you can directly debug the app on an android device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried genymotion. It works (still slower than I'd like) but the free version is missing features. Any ideas for an alternate emulator that allows for accelerometer simulation? (including simulated shaking so I can pull mock data off accelerometer).